# Iterator over all but one index in julia

Tags: matrix, iterator, julia, tensor

i am trying to write a general tensor operation in julia (matrix * tensor of known rank).

My tensor is an object with n indices (e.g. tensor(a_1,a_2,...,a_n) and my matrix only has an effect on the i'th index. Therefore it would be conventient to have an iterator with goes over every but the i'th index. Is there an easy function to implement this, or do you have an idea how to do it with good performance? I also need the result of the iterator in the CartesianIndex-form (i think), because i have to iterate over the last index in a matrix-vector-multiplication style.

My first idea was to get all permutations for the indices before and after the i'th one, but the generation of those seemed tedious...

I hope you can help me, 
best regards,
lepmueller

Comment: are you sure you don't just want to use matrix*tensor multiplication implimented by a package?

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear exactly what you are after. You can get an iterator over the indices that ignore the i'th row of a Matrix like

```
Iterators.filter(x->x[1] != i, CartesianIndices(a))
```

Is that useful for you, or could you edit the question to be more explicit?

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, there is also a nice little package called [InvertedIndices.jl](https://github.com/mbauman/InvertedIndices.jl) which allows you to drop specific columns/rows like so:

```
julia> using InvertedIndices

julia> x = rand(4,4)
4×4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.779118  0.66097   0.335433  0.583011
 0.284284  0.799394  0.353914  0.146769
 0.716189  0.605426  0.2449    0.92238
 0.140876  0.210152  0.810854  0.37236

julia> x[Not(2), Not(4)] # drop second row and 4th column
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.779118  0.66097   0.335433
 0.716189  0.605426  0.2449
 0.140876  0.210152  0.810854
```